# AU instance of LUIS not showing existing apps

Tags: azure-language-understanding

The AU instance of LUIS has stopped showing existing apps.  I've got 2 apps within the AU LUIS instance.  When I go to https://au.luis.ai and login I'm redirected to https://dialogice2.azurewebsites.net/applications and the message is displayed "You haven't created any apps yet".

Both of my LUIS apps are accessible via the API so my application is still usable.  I just can't login to alter any utterances / intents.

Comment: This has now been resolved.  All apps are visible.

Comment: Great!! Thanks for letting us know.